# How to make this greedy function faster?

Tags: python, time-complexity, greedy

I am trying to solve a problem and my code fails at one test case where the list is of length 25000. Is there any way I can make this faster. I tried using `functools.lru_cache` and I still can not run within the time required to complete.

This is the problem from the site

> Given an array of non-negative integers nums, you are initially
> positioned at the first index of the array.
>
> Each element in the array represents your maximum jump length at that
> position.
>
> Determine if you are able to reach the last index.

This is what I have tried

```
def can_jump(input_list):

    @lru_cache
    def helper(idx = 0):
        if idx == len(input_list) - 1:
            return True
        return any(helper(new_idx) for x in range(input_list[idx]) \
        if (new_idx := idx + x + 1) < len(input_list)) # increasing order of jumps

    return helper()
```

Sample test cases work

```
input_list = [2,3,1,1,4]
print(can_jump(input_list)) # True
input_list = [3,2,1,0,4]
print(can_jump(input_list)) # False
```

I have also tried going from the other direction,

```
return any(helper(new_idx) for x in range(input_list[idx], 0, -1) \
if (new_idx := idx + x) < len(input_list)) # decreasing order of jumps
```

But I still can not make this run fast enough to clear the last test case of 25000 element list, what is it that I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the site? It might help if we can figure out the target run time. Even though we could optimize it, it still might not be fast enough.

Comment: This is from leetcode @zerecees

Comment: Ah ok, hang on, let me see what I can find.

Comment: Posted an answer from a different stack exchange below. Let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I get it. Can you try this? Please note, this is taken straight from: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223612/jump-game-leetcode

```
def canjump(nums):
    maximum_reachable_index = 0

    for index, max_jump in enumerate(nums):
        if index > maximum_reachable_index:
            return False

        maximum_reachable_index = max(index + max_jump, maximum_reachable_index)

    return True
```

Comment: Because the answer is on a different stack, I have not marked it as duplicate. However, it may get marked as duplicate in the future, as someone else may have asked the question in a different way.

Comment: ok I will try this, thank you, should I not mark this as an answer then?

Comment: No problem, you're welcome. And, welcome to Stack! Accepting the answer is up to you. If it works, I would say yes. I did some Google-fu and couldn't find the prompt reposted to stack overflow. So, looks like the question is unique, at least on stack overflow.

If you do accept it, I get internet points (yay). If you don't that's fine too (yay, because hopefully it helped).